# Putting siding on a shed, what risks are there in using LP Smartside 38 series on 24 inch studs instead of the recommended 16 inch?

Tags: siding, shed, barn

LP Smartside has two thicknesses, the 76 (7/16) and the 38 (3/8). Instructions say that 76 can be installed on 24 inch studs while 38 needs 16 inch studs. Obviously there is a difference in price. Im just building a barn that won't be insulated. What problems (if any) might arise when using 3/8 Smartside on 24 inch studs instead of 16 inch studs?

Comment: Wavy unstable walls.  Are you going to sheath the walks with plywood first?

Comment: Question states "shed", the body states "a barn", size makes a different and what it is being used for,  Big different in how you construct a small tool shed like 3x5 and a barn that's housing animals.

Comment: @Programmer66 it's a 16x16 gambrel roof barn.

Comment: @Kris no I wasn't planning on sheathing. Sounds like I need to stick with 76 series

Comment: And you are using proper size studs for 24" centers to xfer roof weight to foundation.

Comment: @Programmer66 I'm using the plans here: https://myoutdoorplans.com/shed/16x16-gambrel-shed-plans/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sheeting is in part what will hold the barn up when it is windy I don’t think I would skimp on both the spacing and the siding, you might find it will only be a couple of extra studs and you can use cheaper siding, the same true with your roof. I have saved hundreds on sheathing alone by adding a single truss in some cases 2 but still saved much more than the few studs / trusses it cost to bring it to 16oc